# how to disable previous month and year selection arrows of calendar in magento

Tags: php, magento, date, calendar

In my magento calendar, i disabled all the previous dates based on current date.But even i need to disable my previous year and month selection arrows . But i'm not getting the logic to disable it. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to do this in Magento's frontend or admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

The Below function is used to disable the previous month and date this code works absolutely fine,

Calendar.setup({

```
    inputField: "vacation_mode_to_date",

    ifFormat: "%m/%e/%Y",

    showsTime: false,

    button: "vacation_mode_to_date_trig",

    align: "Bl",

    singleClick: true,

    dateStatusFunc : disabledDate 
    });

//disable the previous month ,year and date
function disabledDate(date)
{
       //getting the current values such as month,year and date
       var today = new Date();
       var current_day = today.getDate();
       var current_year = today.getFullYear();
       var current_month = today.getMonth();
       //getting the other month,date and year
       var month = date.getMonth();
       var day = date.getDate(); 
       var year=date.getFullYear();
       //only current and future values alone be enabled and others are disabled.
       return ((current_year==year)&&(current_month>month) ||current_year>year || (current_month==month)&&(current_year==year)&&(current_day>day));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't disable the cycling of other months/years, just disables the ability to select specific days.